# How to OCR topographic maps

Tags: raster, pdf, digitizing, vectorization

I have old topographic maps that I have scanned and converted into PDF in Acrobat XI 11. I need this PDF to be text-searchable (not mere image). To do this I tried text recognition in Acrobat but it fails, maybe this map is so cluttered so it fails.

I think both manual and automatic OCR may be the solution i.e. first OCR and correct or edit this OCR. Sample of map is attached

[image: Sample of map]

I need to generate **text-searchable pdf**, and asking for help on the correct workflow.

Comment: You might try Acrobat DC; they say that the OCR capabilities have been improved.

Comment: DC is the same wine in new bottle, in my case..

Comment: OK. Another approach which may or may not help, would be to do some color processing, in order to give the (black) text a maximum of contrast.